# Mod_rewrite to handle "data format" parameter

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

my example htaccess file contains code:

```
RewriteRule ^cart$ index.php?controller=cart&action=default [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^listing$ index.php?controller=product&action=listing [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^blog$ index.php?controller=blog&action=listing [L,NC]
```

and I can access the cart by example.com/cart

My question: Is there any possibility to add some extra parameter, for example, "data format" parameter?

I want to have an access to example.com/cart (as html output) and example.com/cart.xml
and other URLs:
example.com/listing.xml
example.com/blog.xml

It is important to me not to modify each of Rewrite Rules. I have hundrets of lines in my htaccess file so it would be so much faster to add some code that modify URL request.

It could work this way:

1. remove .xml from URL
2. match rewrite url
3. add ?format=xml (index.php?controller=blog&action=listing&format=xml)

This feature is commonly used by modern PHP and non-PHP frameworks to output rendered websites as html, xml, json and so on..

@EDIT:

Thanks! I should use QSA flags as you wrote.

Rule that I'm using now to add .xml parameter:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*).xml$ $1?params[output_format]=xml
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use these rules:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+(cart|listing|blog)\.(xml)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1?format=%1 [R=302,L]

RewriteRule ^cart$ index.php?controller=cart&action=default [L,NC,QSA]
RewriteRule ^listing$ index.php?controller=product&action=listing [L,NC,QSA]
RewriteRule ^blog$ index.php?controller=blog&action=listing [L,NC,QSA]
```

- First rule will remove `.xml` from URL and add `?format=xml` query parameter to it.
- Second rule with the QSA flag add remaining query parameters.